# c# call method that returns collection of PSObject

Tags: c#, powershell

I am new to c# from vb and having a hard time figuring out how to run a method.
My full code is below. My question is what should be in the main method. I got the functions from forums that is supposed to let me remote execute exchange admin commands. I am trying to run basic powershell command with remote exchange to see if I can get this to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Remoting;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ExchPwrShellCmdletsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        public Collection<PSObject> GetUsersUsingBasicAuth(string liveIDConnectionUri, string schemaUri, PSCredential credentials, int count)
        {
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
                new Uri(liveIDConnectionUri),
                schemaUri, credentials);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                return GetUserInformation(count, runspace);
            }
        }

        public Collection<PSObject> GetUserInformation(int count, Runspace runspace)
        {
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.AddCommand("Get-Users");
                powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize", count);

                runspace.Open();

                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                return powershell.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: You're missing a main-method.... Nothing to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`public Collection<PSObject> GetUsersUsingBasicAuth(string liveIDConnectionUri, string schemaUri, PSCredential credentials, int count)` is defining a new method in your code. Because it specified `Collection<PSObject>` your return type of this method will be in the form of a `Collection<PSObject>`. To call the method you reference it by name, then pass in any usable parameters.

i.e

`var coll = GetUsersUsingBasicAuth("liveidconnectionurl","schemauri",new PSCredentials(...), 5 );` for your first method defined.

You would use that above code snippet (with actual values) inside of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var coll = GetUsersUsingBasicAuth("liveidconnectionurl","schemauri",new PSCredentials(...), 5 );
}
```